# Services: which hook to use for altering node field values before calling the node retrieve service?

Tags: 7, hooks, services

I have a custom formatter for a field
http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters
but this seems to be ignored during node retrieve.

I also tried altering field value during hook_node_view, but no luck.

Do you have any tips on which hook node could I use to change the display of a field before retrieve?

Comment: currently playing with hook_node_load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think it's only [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) that can be use. As I understand Services module send just data and doesn't do any HTML render of the node and the hook_node_view is actually done only for it : change the HTML render.